# Clicking on different areas in UICollectionViewCell calling different methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a layout like this:
[image]

`UICollectionViewCells` can have varying no. of lines.
When clicked on a cell on 'editable text line 1' or 'editable text line 2' then, the textView becomes the first responder(*`textViewDidBeginEditing` inside the custom UICollectionViewCell is called*)
However when clicked on 'editable text line 3' or any line after it, `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` of `UICollectionView` is called.

Height of the cell in CollectionView is calculated by `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`.

Have searched and applied a lot of ways but none worked.

Can't find what is the cause and how to fix it.Any help is appreciated.
Thank You.